# Trying to populate using JSON, it is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to populate an ul with a set of options by using JSON.

**THE JSON:**

```
{
       "product": {
            "options":{
               "42432":{
                  "id":42432,
                  "title":"Kies uw datum",
                  "values":{
                    "166655":{
                      "id":166655,
                      "title":"do 8 mei 2014",
                      "active":true
                    },
                    "152744":{
                      "id":152744,
                      "title":"za 17 mei 2014",
                      "active":false
                    },
                    "166656":{
                      "id":166656,
                      "title":"wo 4 juni 2014",
                      "active":false
                    }
                 }
              }
           },
         }
}
```

**MY HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="infoproduct infoboxcsdata">   
     <ul class="datacursuscoll datacursusul">
     </ul>
</div>
```

**MY SCRIPT:**

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
           $.get('http://exampleproduct.html?format=json', function(data){     
             if (data.product.options) {
               $.each(data.product.options, function(index, values){
                 var vartitle = value.title
                     $('.infoproduct .datacursuscoll').append('<li>' + vartitle + '</li>'); 
               });
             }
           });
         });
</script>
```

However, this is not working, the fault is probably in the script. What's wrong with it and how can I fix it?

**What I want:**

```
<ul>
<li>do 8 mei 2014</li>
<li>za 17 mei 2014</li>
<li>wo 4 juni 2014</li>
</ul>
```

**What I know now:**
The 'options' is also a loop, but how do I make a loop inside a loop with JSON?

Comment: $('.info_{{ product.id }} ...

your .info does not have any "_id" no ?

Comment: Could be anything, what's coming back from the server?

Comment: @Maxime sorry this was a fault, I changed it. Hasn't fixed it though.

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat sorry, I can not check that...

Comment: It would seem that you can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `value` inside the loop, but the object is in the parameter `values`.

```
$.each(data.product.options, function(index, values){
  var vartitle = values.title;
  $('.info_{{ product.id }} .datacursuscoll_{{ product.id }}').append('<li>' + vartitle + '</li>');
});
```

#### Edit:

To loop through the inner object, you use a loop inside the loop:

```
$.each(data.product.options, function(index, values){
  $.each(values.values, function(index2, values2){
    var vartitle = values2.title;
    $('.info_{{ product.id }} .datacursuscoll_{{ product.id }}').append('<li>' + vartitle + '</li>');
  });
});
```

Comment: I Changed it to: values.title and got: "Kies uw datum" back

Comment: @Niek95: Yes, that is the title of the object. If you want the objects inside that object, you need another loop inside the loop.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! The options is also a loop, but how do I make a loop inside the loop in JSON?

Comment: @Niek95: I added an example above.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer... but there are a lot of engines to do what you're trying to do in a more concise and effective way. Try [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Use $.ajax() function

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://exampleproduct.html', 
    data : {
         'format' : 'json'
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data){     
             if (data.product.options) {
               $.each(data.product.options, function(index, values){
                 var vartitle = values.title
                     $('.info_{{ product.id }} .datacursuscoll_{{ product.id }}').append('<li>' + vartitle + '</li>'); 
               });
             }
           });
```

Comment: i edited answer, you have bug in line `var vartitle = value.title`

change to: `var vartitle = values.title`